# Android add a picture in the top right of a button programmatically

Tags: java, android, button, uiimageview

I have a button and I want to pro grammatically add a picture of a green tick to the top right button after it has been selected, how would one do that?

Comment: Provided details are too less to help you

Comment: I am not sure how to make it less vague, how does one add a picture to the top right hand corner of a button

Comment: Add a ImageButton in your XML and programatically set the image src as per requirement

Comment: doesnt an imageButton cover the entire button with an image?

Comment: either the src that you set should be equal to size of your image view else set the image as image button background... it will entire image in give imagebutton space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First call the relative layout family and using LayoutPram update the position of the picture

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.theImage);

Button myBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.myButton);
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
               RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams();
               params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
               params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
               imageView.setLayoutParams(params); 
          }
      });
```

Try this!

Answer (score -1):

Use ImageButton and onClick swap out the image

Its a vague answer but your question is also vague

Comment: dont want the whole button to be a picture, just i want a small picture in the top right hand corner